# Count neighbours in 2d array by java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a 2d array like this:

```
0,1,1,1,0
0,1,0,1,1
1,0,1,0,1
1,1,1,0,0
0,0,1,0,0
```

I'd like to count the sum of neighbouring cells when the number is 1.

Ex. for i=1, j=1 the sum is 4.

It isn't a problem the count with a loop, but is it possible to count by java stream (and ArrayList instead tab[][] of course)?

```
private void countAlive(Cell[][] cell) {

        for (int i = 0; i < cell.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cell[0].length; j++) {
                cell[i][j].setAlive(0);
                if (cell[i - 1][j - 1].cellAlive())
                    cell[i][j].increaseAlive();
                if (cell[i - 1][j].cellAlive())
                    cell[i][j].increaseAlive();
                if (cell[i - 1][j + 1].cellAlive())
                    cell[i][j].increaseAlive();
                if (cell[i][j - 1].cellAlive())
                    cell[i][j].increaseAlive();
                if (cell[i][j + 1].cellAlive())
                    cell[i][j].increaseAlive();
                if (cell[i + 1][j - 1].cellAlive())
                    cell[i][j].increaseAlive();
                if (cell[i + 1][j].cellAlive())
                    cell[i][j].increaseAlive();
                if (cell[i + 1][j + 1].cellAlive())
                    cell[i][j].increaseAlive();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It wouldn't make much sense in the "real" world to do that, but of course, it would be an interesting education project. But for education projects, the first step would be that *you* try it yourself. So, please add your own efforts, this is not a free code writing service here.

Comment: Sounds like minesweeper

Comment: A coding effort on your part would also describe for us more accurately the problem, what you start with and what your end result should be.

Comment: @GhostCat post edited - could you make it easier with java stream (of course with ArrayList than tab[][])

Comment: @tryman post edited - could you make it easier with java stream (of course with ArrayList than tab[][])

Comment: Why do you think that using a concept that is kind of "alien" to arrays will help you to simplify your current code? And honestly: try/catch for IndexOutOfBounds and ignoring that exception is **really** bad style (in java).

Comment: @GhostCat omg .. u just wanted example so I added. I only want to know about streams .. it's fast example ..

Comment: I think that what drives you to use streams is the notion of trying to write the same code in a more 'functional' style. But, functional is not automatically translated to streams. In this example, the proper functional equivalent is 'recursion'.

Comment: @GhostCat I'm learning about streams and I just want to know that it's way to use stream in that case

Comment: I understand, but then: streams() are a specific construct for java Collections. What exactly makes you think that they are a good solution to everything? And as said: this sounds educational. What have you studied about streams, and what prevents you from writing your own code?!

Comment: @GhostCat so the question is it possible to use streams for 2d arrays when u have to know about pervious and next array? It's much easier for 1d to do many stream constructions but is it possible for example above - I think in that way the code would be more clear

Comment: And I don't understand why for that question I've received negative points ..

Comment: Anything in software is possible. The real question: does it make sense?! I think MaxG nailed it. You shouldnt just use some concept you heard of (there are streams) and assume that this concept nicely solves "all" kinds of problems.

Comment: @GhostCat ok, so the best solution is user standard loops (for) instead of steams in that case? Not always are streams better, right? Just it was my indirectly question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams are great for abstracting the way the iteration is done and focusing on the actual process you want to perform on/with the object. However this is useful when the iteration order does not matter. In this case it does: not the order itself, but the object's indexes at each step, essentially its relative position in comparison to the other objects of the 2D array. When you stream that array Cell[][] you get a single Cell object at a time, without its indexes.

```
Arrays(array2DofCells).stream().flatMap(x ->Arrays.stream(x))
.forEach( cell -> { //What would you do here without the indexes? } )
```

One way, would be for each Cell to know its indexes so that you can call `cell.getRowIndex()` and `cell.getColumnIndex()` and do the procedures you want to do on the parent 2D array.

However, as pointed in the comments, unless there is a very specific reason, this seems to be a case to avoid streams. The pointer for that is that you start wondering inside the scope of the .forEach() how to get information that the stream intentionally hides.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for something similar to this:

```
var cells = [
"01110",
"01011",
"10101",
"11100",
"00100",
];

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
for (var j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++) {
if (cells[i][j - 1] == "1") {cellAlive();}
if (cells[i][j + 1] == "1") {cellAlive();}
if (cells[i - 1][j] == "1") {cellAlive();}
if (cells[i + 1][j] == "1") {cellAlive();}
}
}
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, could you please be more specific? Hope this helps!

Comment: In java stream for 1d array it looks like
IntStream.of(1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0).filter(i -> i == 1).count();
is it possible to count above neighbors with java stream instead of loops (for)?

Comment: look to my comment above - I pressed enter to fast ;)

Comment: Loops in my opinion tend to be more efficient, but I think you can if you fiddle around with it enough.

Comment: Ok, but do you know how to do it with streams? Because I don't know but I'm curious

Comment: I don't know, sorry.